# How to check when a bluetooth file has been received (Android)?

Tags: java, android, file, bluetooth

I would like my android app to execute some functionality upon receiving a file via bluetooth from another device. One way I know of is just to keep looking in the "Bluetooth" folder for the file to see if it is there (could be very resource consuming). But I was wondering if there is someway to get like a status update/notification that my android app can pick up?

Thanks!

Comment: "One way I know of is just to keep looking in the "Bluetooth" folder for the file to see if it is there" -- you assume that all implementations of "receiving a file via bluetooth" result in a "Bluetooth" folder.

Comment: When you read bytes from stream check if it ends with EOF, if it's, then run the desired code.

Comment: Yes, if there is no other way, then I will just periodically check the bluetooth folder, but I feel like this is a really dumb and resource intensive procedure and would result in more delays (the polling interval) as compared to getting some sort of status update. I did find some stuff about using bluetooth sockets, does anybody have experience with that? And would that solve my problem? Thanks.